# Python | Multiprocessing | Split Data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement **multiprocessing in python** in a HPC cluster with  **4 nodes**, where each node has **8 processors**. I have a user defined function (let's call it '**func**'), which I want implement for **64 different arguments**.

I have just started acquainting myself with the operation of multiprocessing with python. I know how to use multithreading, but if I do that here, then I will be able to use a single node only (8 processors). I will very much appreciate any help. This is the sketch of code that I have at this stage.

```
import numpy as np
import user_func as uf

Data = [D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9, D10, ... , D64 ]
Results = [R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, ... , R64 ]

for i in range( len(Data) ):
     Results[i] = uf.func( Data[i] )

Final_R = sum(Results)
```

In the full version of my code, the arguments (data, D1, D2 ..., D64) are imported from files. Also in my full code, I initialize all values in the list Results as zeros.

As can be seen from the version of the sketch of my code, I have to combine all the results in end (*I have used a simple function* **sum** *in this example; its a more complicated function in my original code*.) Because of this, I suspect I may need to also use **sharing of memory between processors across different nodes**.

I will be thankful to have any help on how I can implement this functionality (3 nodes, 8 processors and 64 arguments).

Comment: I don't see where the multiprocessing in this code...
If this is a sketch then consider using `map` for this.
Sharing data between processes is done over network (but invisible to the user), read about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues

Comment: Alon Alexander: Thanks for the help. I am taking a look at the link that you suggested. This sketch is the version of the code that I have (one processor, one node). I want to parallelize this code (across multiple nodes) and run it in an HPC cluster, but I am just beginning to acquaint myself with the nuances of processing across multiple nodes in python.

Comment: You should probably consider using a more robust and managed solution such as [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) to solve your problem.

Comment: @Udi Thanks for the suggestion. Could you direct me to a place where I can see an example and learn the implementation of MapReduce in python (and apply that to the problem at hand)? I will hugely appreciate if someone can give me a small sketch of the parallelization of the code here.

Comment: @SiddTheKid Have you looked at `map` in multiprocessing in python (Pools, Workers, etc.)?

Comment: @AlonAlexander: This will be the first time I will try multiprocessing across multiple nodes and processors. I am seeing if I can get some useful example from the link that you mentioned in your previous post (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) and a few YouTube videos. Thanks very for remembering and asking again. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken directly from the documentation of Python 2, you can you `Pool` from the Python multiprocessing package and its `map` method.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

From here you can replace `f` with your custom function and `[1, 2, 3]` with your data (you might need to use `zip` and then unpack them to pass multiple arguments or use `apply` instead of `map`. For more information read the 
[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)).

Exaplanation  of the example above:

- First of all, we `import` from the `multiprocessing` module its `Pool` Class. This class can hold and run many processes (invisible to the programmer).
- Then we create the function `f` which we will use later on our data (you can replace this function with whichever function you want).
- Now we create a pool of 'workers' (processes) of size 5 (5 processes) and then we use the `map` method of `Pool` to call these workers on `f` with each of the arguments one by one (but parallel).

If the order of the calls does not matter to you, take a look at `map_async` (and `apply_async`).